# UML Association Class on a recursive association

Tags: database, uml

is possibile to create an association class which is son of a recursive association?

For istance, if I have a class called USER, a recursive association called Send-Feed, from USER TO USER, this last association could have its own association class in which i can put attributes? Don't know if this is clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "son of"? What is a "Send-Feed"? An association doesn't normally "have its own association class", an association can BE an association class. Please clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create some complex association, you should create the association from User to User, create a class for association and connect that class with the association. The tool for that last connection will be called as Association Class or something similar. Of course, its existence depends on the modelling tool.

[image]

Now you can set not only the usual Association attributes on its ends, but anything - as members of the Association class.

Comment: Ok that is what I was trying to say, I'm Italian and I dunno the exact translation (and also the meaning often) of this things. I was only wondering if in UML the scheme created by Gangnus it was legit